# glutGetWindow - Expression must have class type

Tags: c++, glut

Good Afternoon,

So I'm working with C++ (Visual Studios C++ 2010 to be exact) and am working on a seemingly easy task;

Draw a picture onto the middle of the window. If you readjust the window size, the picture/bitmap will be redrawn into the middle of the newly sized window.

I figure to get the middle of the window, I should find its rightmost and bottommost bits, then divide each by 2, but I don't know how to get the window length and height.

I currently have

```
centrewidth = glutGetWindow().Size.Width;
centreheight = glutGetWindow().Size.Height;
```

Yet for both I'm getting errors on glutGetWindow, saying "Error: Expression must have class type". I'm certain once I get this, it will be no problem, but this is causing a lot of trouble for me. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glutGetWindow` doesn't return object of any class type. It's signature is this:

```
int glutGetWindow(void);
```

And you need is this (see [doc](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node70.html)):

```
int glutGet(GLenum eWhat);
```

Example,

```
int width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH); //Width in pixels of the current window.
int height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT); //Height in pixels of the current window.
```

Have a look at the [doc](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node70.html) to know what *states* you can get using this function.

Comment: Thanks! this was a big help, but I still have a few other bugs to work out. I appreciate the help!